# Cannot run script using web3py

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, web3py

My OS is Linux Ubuntu 16.04 - ec2 amazon; I am using python3.6

I have tried on different servers, time 0 reinstalled python

```
ubuntu@1:~/Desktop/ico$ python3 token.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "token.py", line 8, in <module>
    from web3.providers.eth_tester import EthereumTesterProvider
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ico/web3.py/web3/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import zipfile
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 13, in <module>
    import shutil
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 22, in <module>
    import bz2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/bz2.py", line 19, in <module>
    from threading import RLock
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 7, in <module>
    from traceback import format_exc as _format_exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/tokenize.py", line 35, in <module>
    from token import *
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ico/token.py", line 8, in <module>
    from web3.providers.eth_tester import EthereumTesterProvider
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ico/web3.py/web3/providers/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .base import (  # noqa: F401
  File "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ico/web3.py/web3/providers/base.py", line 4, in <module>
    from eth_utils import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eth_utils/__init__.py", line 97, in <module>
    __version__ = pkg_resources.get_distribution("eth-utils").version
AttributeError: module 'pkg_resources' has no attribute 'get_distribution'
```

Comment: You forgot to explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please add the content of the `token.py` file you are running when getting this error? If there is a lot of code in that file you might have to strip it down to a [mcve].

Comment: This appears to be an incompatibility in the ``eth_utils`` library you are using. You should contact the developers.